# Кнопка только для авторизированых пользователей Laravel

Tags: laravel, auth

Хочу сделать кнопку которую видят только авторизированые пользователи. 
Думаю просто и изящно было бы так :

```
@can(Условие)
<button>
@endcan
```

Вопрос: Какое должно быть условие пропускающее только любого авторизированого пользователя?

Comment: директива `@can` работает не как `@if`, она проверяет на наличие доступа у юзера прав через политики laravel. Антон ответил ниже на вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для версии 5.4

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <button>
@endif
```

Для версии 5.5 и выше

```
@auth
    <button>
@endauth
```

Comment: стоит уточнить, что работать это будет только если использован родной механизм авторизации Laravel. В противном случае нужно будет делать через `@if (myAuthCheck()) { ... } @endif`